# Insert php - query error

Tags: php, mysql

i have problem. where i want to make insert new row by retrieve some data before. Then i input 2 new data and click button submit. I already echo the data for all variable and get all data, but cannot be insert into db and show query error. this is my code

*Matric,Cat_name and Product_name - data that retrieve.
*error at query $sql

```
if (isset($_POST['add']))   {

    $Matric = $_POST['Matric'];
    $Total_sales = $_POST['Total_sales'];       
    $Cat_name= addslashes($_POST['Cat_name']);
    $Product = addslashes($_POST['Product_name']);
    $tarikh = addslashes($_POST['Date']);

    $data = "SELECT participant.*,sales.* FROM participant 
    LEFT JOIN sales ON sales.Matric = participant.Matric
    WHERE sales.Product_name='$Product'" ;
    $result = mysql_query($data) or die('SQL error');
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

    $gambar =  $row['img'];

    echo $Matric;
    echo $Total_sales;
    echo $Cat_name;
    echo $Product;
    echo $tarikh;
    echo $gambar;


    $sql="INSERT INTO sales (Matric, Total_sales, Cat_name, Product_name, img, Date) values ('$Matric', '$Total_sales', '$Cat_name', '$Product', '$gambar', '$tarikh')";
    $result=mysql_query($sql) or die("Suck");


    if ($result)
        echo 'Add  success';
    else
        echo 'Add  fail';

}
```

Comment: Change `die("Suck")` to `die(mysql_error())` so you see the reason for the error.

Comment: i get error - duplicate entry . i want to duplicate the entry for Cat_name and Product_name

Comment: That means you have a unique key in your table, which prevents you from duplicating those columns. If you need to allow duplicates, change the index to non-unique.

Comment: but i dont have unique key .. still cannot duplicate

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: Duplicate entry 'food-chips more' for key 'Matric'

Comment: That clearly says there's a unique key on `Matric`. Is it the primary key? The PK is a unique key.

Comment: Matric is not the primary key ..

Comment: Add `show create table sales` output to your question.

Answer (score 4):

Date is a reserved keyword use backtick operator to escape it

```
$sql="INSERT INTO sales (Matric, Total_sales, Cat_name, Product_name, img, `Date`) values ('$Matric', '$Total_sales', '$Cat_name', '$Product', '$gambar', '$tarikh')";
```

Comment: Welcome, an I'll take out the comments now

Answer (score 2):

Date is Reserved keyword

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

try with using

> 'Date'

Comment: I think you are referring to backticks

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql="INSERT INTO sales (Matric, Total_sales, Cat_name, Product_name, img, `Date`) values ('{$Matric}', '{$Total_sales}', '{$Cat_name}', '{$Product}', '{$gambar}', '{$tarikh}')";
```

Variables under "" are userd under {}

Answer (score -1):

Date is Reserved keyword. use any other name.

Comment: Date can be a field name provided you have backticks